# What are the various context clue techniques children use to learn a new word?

Tags: learning-methods, children, native-language, context

Is there any literature that discusses in great detail what the various context clues are that children use to learn a new word? I found myself reading a few papers *"The development of a classification
scheme of contextual aids*" by Wilbur S. Ames and "*Classifying the Context Clues in Children's Text*" by Susan J. Parault Dowds. And they both mention a few types of context clues, such as the one listed below:

1. Association
2. Cause and effect
3. Comparison or contrast
4. etc..

But the problem is that they don't seem to go into more details. Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.